# Machine Reports Incorrect Number of CPU Cores

Tags: windows, cpu, hardware-detection

I have a Windows® machine running an Intel® Core™ 2 Duo Processor E7200 with two cores. Not long ago, the machine reported it as having a CPU with two (2) cores. Now it reports as having a CPU with just a single core.

I have tried searching Google but I did not find any answers.

Any ideas on why this is happening?

**UPDATE:**
It turns out it was an OS issue. I did a repair install to fix other issues. Now the machine reports the correct CPU count (cores).

Comment: How is it displayed in the "device manager" in the "processors" section? Which version of windows is this? "the machine reports it. . " where?

Comment: I second @Psycogeek request. We need more details. I suspect your HAL (Hardware Abstraction Layer) in Windows got changed to Uniprocessor (single CPU), but without the extra info it's impossible to confirm this.

Answer (score 1):

Check BIOS to see if MAX CPU ID Value is disabled or set to 1.4 (must not be 1).
Check TaskManager - View - CPU History - One Graph, All CPUs (must be off). 
To check the true specs of your CPU, you can use [CPU-ID](http://www.cpuid.com/softwares/cpu-z.html).

Comment: in fact using CPU-ID did I noticed that the number of CPU cores being reported is incorrect.

Comment: Then it's most likely the wrong setting from BIOS.

Comment: I did but still the same. Although I'll take it as a symptom of the machine showing its age...

Comment: @JCM An old machine that's working shouldn't suddenly "loose" a CPU core. There will be a reason why you're only seeing one CPU, and I'd bet it's OS related.

Comment: @misha256 probably. Anyway, soon I will deep six it and get a replacement.

Comment: @JCM Lol, good plan, those Core 2s are getting on a bit! Still, for the benefit of others, you might want to see this question through to an answer. Otherwise it'll sit here orphaned providing no value to anyone else with a similar problem. If you just provide us a couple more details as requested I'm pretty confident we'll know what's going on.

Comment: @misha256 the machine is still running an old OS [MS] which  from time to time gets a hiccup and generally requires a sacrifice to make it run.